# How to encode a long string of hex values in unicode easily in python

Tags: python, unicode, codepoint

I have hex code point values for a long string. For a short one, following is fine.

```
msg = unichr(0x062A) + unichr(0x0627) + unichr(0x0628)
print msg
```

However, since unichr's alternate api unicode() does exist, i thought there must be a way to pass an entire code point string to it. So far i wasn't able to do it.

Now i have to type in a string of 150 hex values (code points) like the 3 above to generate a complete string. I was hoping to get something like

```
msg = unicode('0x062A, 0x0627....')
```

I have to use 'msg' latter. Printing it was a mere example. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand this, you want to type `'0x062A, 0x0627....'` but balk at `'\u062a\u0627...'`. So type the first one then use the global replace function in your editor; that's what it's for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
", ".join(unichr(u) for u in (0x062A, 0x0627, 0x0628))
```

Result:

```
u'\u062a, \u0627, \u0628'
```

**Edit:** This uses [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell what you're asking for exactly.  Are you looking for `u'\u062A\u0627\u0628'`?  The `\u` escape lets you enter individual characters by code point in a unicode string.

Comment: yes i am looking for merely a combined string which i can latter say pass to a url with msg.encode('utf-16') etc.

Comment: @fayyazki: So are you saying the answer I gave is or is not what you are looking for?

Comment: No it does the job. Only that i have to enter a \u for every code point value. Using string.join might seem easier (i am going to try it), since i can just copy paste the entire hex string in code and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Following your example:

```
>>> c = u'\u062A\u0627\u0628'
>>> print c
تاب
```

Comment: Thanks! The above though works and is one possible way, but i still have to enter a \u in front of every code point value. I am going to try with join since that seems to work with simply pasting entire hex string in the middle